# How can I store 2 points as a pair and have a list of pairs in Java?

Tags: java, swing, line, graphics2d

I'm drawing lines on a jpanel as a buffered image using graphics 2D and I want to store the points as pairs, i.e the x and y coordinates of the start point as a pair and the x and y coordinates of the end point as another pair. As there will be several lines, I want to store all these pairs as a list(or maybe 2 - one for start points and one for end points) and be able to update them if the line is moved and the points change and check if given points are in the list. How can I do this and is this possible?

I've looked at having a Pair class, but I don't know how exactly it works and if I can have a list of Pairs. Also I've looked at using a maps and arraylists but none of them seem to have the functionality I'm looking for (or maybe I just don't know).

At the moment, I'm just drawing the lines but the points aren't being stored. This is the class that does all the drawing:

```
package floorplan;

/**
*
* @author xodkx
*/

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class Floor extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{


  private static final int WIDTH = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please    
  enter the width of your room"));
  private static final int LENGTH = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please   
  enter the width of your room"));
  private static final Color BACKGROUND = Color.WHITE;
  private static final Color INITIAL_COLOUR = Color.BLACK;
  private static final Framework INITIAL_FRAMEWORK = Framework.FLEXIBLEWALL;

  private MouseState state = MouseState.IDLE;
  private Framework frameworkType = INITIAL_FRAMEWORK;
  private Color colour = INITIAL_COLOUR;



  private Point start = null; // START POINT
  private Point end = null; // END POINT


  private BufferedImage bufImage = null;


  public Floor()
  {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(LENGTH,WIDTH));
    setBackground(Color.white);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder (Color.black, 5));

    this.addMouseListener(this);
    this.addMouseMotionListener(this);

 }

 public void setColor(Color color)
 {
    colour = color;

 }

 public void setFramework(Framework framework)
 {
    frameworkType = framework;
 }

 @Override
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
 {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,   
     RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    if(bufImage == null)
    {
        int h = this.getHeight();
        int w = this.getWidth();
        bufImage = (BufferedImage)this.createImage(h,w);
        Graphics2D gc = bufImage.createGraphics();
        gc.setColor(BACKGROUND);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    }


    g2.drawImage(bufImage,null,0,0);

    drawGrid(g2);

    if(state == MouseState.DRAGGING)
    {
        createComponent(g2);
    }
 }

 public void drawGrid(Graphics g2)
 {
    int gridDivisions = 20;
    int divisionSize = WIDTH/gridDivisions;
    int grid = WIDTH*LENGTH;

    g2.setColor(Color.lightGray);

    for(int i=1; i<grid; i++)
    {
        int x = i * divisionSize;
        g2.drawLine(x,0,x,getSize().height);
    }

    for(int i=1; i<grid; i++)
    {
        int y = i*divisionSize;
        g2.drawLine(0,y,getSize().width,y);
    }
 }


 public void createComponent(Graphics2D g2)
 {
     g2.setColor(colour);

    switch (frameworkType)
    {
        case FLEXIBLEWALL:
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
            g2.drawLine(start.x, start.y, end.x,end.y);
            break;

        case VERTICALWALL:
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
            end.x = start.x;
            g2.drawLine(start.x,start.y,end.x,end.y);
            break;

        case HORIZONTALWALL:
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
            end.y = start.y;
            g2.drawLine(start.x,start.y,end.x,end.y);

        case DOOR:
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
            g2.drawLine(start.x, start.y, end.x,end.y);
            break;

        case WINDOW:
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
            g2.drawLine(start.x, start.y, end.x,end.y);
            break;


        default:
            g2.drawString("test", 10, 20);
            break;
     }
 }

 public void clear() 
 {

    bufImage.flush();
    bufImage = null;
    repaint();
 }


 @Override
 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
 {
    state = MouseState.DRAGGING;
    start = e.getPoint();
    end = start;
 }

 @Override

 public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
 {

    state = MouseState.DRAGGING;
    end = e.getPoint();
    this.repaint();

 }

  @Override
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
 {
    end = e.getPoint();
    if(state == MouseState.DRAGGING)
    {
        state = MouseState.IDLE;
        createComponent(bufImage.createGraphics());
        this.repaint();
    }
 }

 public void updateLocation(MouseEvent e)
 {

 }


 @Override
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
 {

 }

 @Override
 public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
 {

 }

 @Override
 public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
 {

 }



 @Override
 public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
 {

 }

}
```

Comment: You have Points, so why you dont use Line? see my anser below

Comment: i dont understand the downvite, because 6 suboptimal answers have been delivered.

Comment: hmmm can @downvoter(s) post your answer(s) here

Answer (score 3):

Use `java.awt.geom.Line2D`. You can put it into lists, or any other collection. it has `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

You can either use the `Line2D.Float` which needs less space as `Line2D.Double` which is more handy in calculations.

If you have hundred thousands of such lines then things change. Then it gets less comfortable. For that a `int[]` is most memory efficient, but this is another question.

Comment: There's no java.awt.geom.Line as far as I can tell. Apart from that this answer makes the most sense. You might also want to add that the OP can use a `List` of these, since he seems confused on the point.

Comment: @AlexWien I dont want to use line because I want to be able to move points and therefore move a line. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean, could you explain further? Thanks

Comment: @odk You can move line ends by calling `setLine (Point2D, Point2D)` method, but this is not too elegant.

Comment: @odk line is a class that stores a pair of (x,y) coordinates. you can set and get the line points as you like. further it has convenience functions like equals, hashcode, maybe intersects() already implemented

Comment: @AlexWein thanks. Quick question, using line, are the points predefined? or will it still work with the mouse functionality I'm using now?

Comment: @odk You mean that you want to use your own class `Point`, not standard `Point` from `java.awt` package?

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov No, I just want to get the points when the mouse is pressed, not by specifying g2.draw((new Line2D.Double(100,500,200, 600)); for example

Answer (score 0):

```
package util;

public final class Pair<S,T> {
 public S first;
 public T second;

 public Pair(S first, T second) {
    super();
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
 }

 public S getFirst() {
    return first;
 }

 public T getSecond() {
    return second;
 }

 public void setFirst(S first) {
    this.first = first;
 }

 public void setSecond(T second) {
    this.second = second;
 }


 @Override
 public int hashCode() {
     final int prime = 31;
     int result = 1;
     result = prime * result + ((first == null) ? 0 : first.hashCode());
     result = prime * result + ((second == null) ? 0 : second.hashCode());
     return result;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
     if (this == obj)
         return true;
     if (obj == null)
         return false;
     if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
         return false;
     Pair<?,?> other = (Pair<?,?>) obj;
     if (first == null) {
         if (other.first != null)
             return false;
     } else if (!first.equals(other.first))
         return false;
     if (second == null) {
         if (other.second != null)
             return false;
     } else if (!second.equals(other.second))
         return false;
     return true;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
     return "<"+first+","+second+">";
 }

}
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm not sure what you're doing here. Could you please explain?

Comment: A generic Pair class, similar to the std::pair, which can be used  for storing pairs of anything.

Re-reading your question, I agree that using Line2D for your case is more convenient because you have to call methods from the geometry API.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you can store all points in one list, so points at even positions will be starting points of line segments and points at odd positions will be ending points:

```
List <Point> points = Arrays.asList (
    new Point (100, 100), new Point (200, 100),  // First line segment
    new Point (200, 100), new Point (200, 200),  // Second line segment
    new Point (200, 200), new Point (100, 100)); // Third line segment
```

Also, you may store arrays of points in a list, so each array will represent a curve, where curve of cause may contain just one segment:

```
List <Point []> points = Arrays.asList (
    new Point [] {new Point (100, 100), new Point (200, 100)},  // First line segment
    new Point [] {new Point (200, 100), new Point (200, 200)},  // Second line segment
    new Point [] {new Point (200, 200), new Point (200, 100), new Point (100, 100)); // Curve of third and fourth segments
```

And of cause you can declare your own class to store two points like this:

```
public class TwoPoints
{
    public final Point begin;
    public final Point end;

    public TwoPoints (int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
    {
        this (new Point (x1, y1), new Point (x2, y2));
    }

    public TwoPoints (Point begin, Point end)
    {
        this.begin = begin;
        this.end = end;
    }
}
```

And objects of this class you definitely can store in the list:

```
List <TwoPoints> lines = Arrays.asList (
    new TwoPoints (100, 100, 100, 200),  // First line segment
    new TwoPoints (100, 200, 200, 200),  // Second line segment
    new TwoPoints (200, 200, 100, 100)); // Third line segment
```